# How do I set image src based on li active status?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code

```
<li><a href="/business/account" id="accountLnk" class="list-group-item"><img src="/business/resources/images/btn_dashboard.png" height="100px" width="70%" class="img-responsive img-rounded center-block"></a></li>
```

I'd like to change the img src into `btn_dashboard_active.png` when the li has `class="active"`

How can I do this in CSS or Bootstrap ?

Comment: You need to use background image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achive that by deleting the *src*, *height*, *width* attributes inside your *IMG* tag. Then set them in CSS (like in the jsFiddle example below), with the mention that the image paths (the links inside *src* attribute) will become the *content*'s value.

For displaying different images when li has class *active*, just change the *content*'s value (the path) inside *li.active>a>img* selector.

```
li.active>a>img{
content:url("/business/resources/images/btn_dashboard_active.png");
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/L3qsmeje/

Comment: Nice one, Didn't know you can do it.

Answer (score 2):

Use an alternating image which shows up on demand.

html:

```
<li>
<a href="/business/account" id="accountLnk" class="list-group-item">
<img src="/business/resources/images/btn_dashboard.png" height="100px" width="70%" class="img-normal img-responsive img-rounded center-block">
<img src="/business/resources/images/btn_dashboard_active.png" height="100px" width="70%" class="img-active img-responsive img-rounded center-block">
</a>
</li>
```

css:

```
li .img-normal, li.active .img-active{
    display:block;
}
li .img-active, li.active .img-normal{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: The image needs to change when the **li** element has the 'active' class :)

Comment: when li.active the css hides the "img-normal" class and shows the "img-active" class